# Binding To Class Data Without Namespace

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0

### Scenario

I have a class which looks something like this:

```
class GlobalAssemblyInfo
{
    public const string AssemblyName = "MyAppName";
}
```

The class is **NOT** contained in a namespace.

I tried unsuccessfully to bind to this using the following code:

```
Text="{Binding GlobalAssemblyInfo.AssemblyName}"
```

### Question

Is this possible, and if so, how would I accomplish this?

### Why I Need This

Before I get any comments about only using bindings for dynamically changing content, let me explain why I need this.

I am creating an app which may need to undergo a rename due to trademark issues. I need to use the name in several places, such as "MyApp Contributors" or "MyApp Help." Using a binding would enable me to say merely `Text="{Binding AppName, StringFormat='{}{0} Contributors'}"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems here. The first is that the way you're using the class in the binding is assigning it to the Path so it is looking for a property named GlobalAssemblyInfo on whatever your DataContext is. You instead need to use a static source and also expose the value as a property instead of a const. This uses the form:

{Binding Source={x:Static ns:Class.StaticProperty}}

The other problem is that you have no namespace to create your xmlns from in XAML. You should consider if you really need the class to not be namespaced but if you do you should be able to use the weird construction of

xmlns:myGlobal="clr-namespace:;assembly="

where you would then use myGlobal in the place of ns in the first example.

Comment: Cool, this works. I didn't know I could just leave the clr-namespace field blank.

Answer (score 1):

If you created a class that has no namespace, why don't you just put your assembly name in `Resources` in `XAML` or `Resources` in project so you can do binding in it with `StringFormat`

In your `App.xaml.`

Define something like this

```
<x:String x:Key="AssemblyName">Your Value</x:String>
```

or add a new resource file in your project and define it there.

So you can use it something like this

```
Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource AssemblyName}, Path=., StringFormat="{}}"
```

Comment: I didn't place it in resources because I also wanted to be able to access the data quickly from the C#.

Comment: You can access it quickly from C# too. I'm talking about the `resx` file in this case.

Comment: Yeah, but there is still a small amount of overhead in that scenario.

Comment: @MingSlogar My first answer was just binding it statically, but then you didn't want to have a namespace on that class for whatever reason. I gave you options.